# "A few does" or "A few do"

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

Is the word "A few" a plural or a singular?
 "A few does" or "a few do"?

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+few+does+%2C+a+few+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20does%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20do%3B%2Cc0

//sorry I am working in a phone. I can't paste a link.

Comment: Try using *A* in uppercase instead of lowercase and you will see the difference. Also, we can say "we saw a few does", because "doe" means a female deer.

Comment: It's plural. _After 8PM, a few **leave** the meeting, but most stay here until the end_ (not _a few leaves the meeting_). Or, _You'll see a few **swim** here every morning before dawn_ (not _a few swims here_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on the page of N-Gram you link to, you click through "[a few does](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20few%20does%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en)", you will see in most examples the "does" in question is not the third person singular of the verb "to do", but the plural of the noun "doe" -- a female deer.  Example:

> I got in the stand before daylight, and by 11 o'clock I'd seen a few does and one fairly nice buck, maybe a 130, but I let him walk.

"A few" is plural, and takes "do".

**Addendum:** Oh, hey, google's N-Gram doesn't respect punctuation, and there's quite a lot of "a few does" hits which have punctuation between "few" and "does" which completely changes the relationship of the words.  Examples:

> Does she have many memories or just **a few? Does** she enjoy thinking about and remembering them?
>
> Does that man take boarders? He takes **a few. Does** that woman keep a boarding-house?
>
> Thus **'a few' does** not rule out the possibility that an All statement is true. 'A few' is a positive quantifier, which Oaksford et al. designate by Few+ (Moxey and Sanford 1987, 1991; Paterson et al. 1998;Sanford et al. 1994, 1996).
>
> It is an old maxim that "he who mentions **a few, does** not deny that there are more."

Apparently google's N-Gram viewer isn't necessarily so good for phrases.

Comment: I was amused that one of the hits is the novel _Watership Down_, reminding me that a "doe" is also a female rabbit.  ETA: Oh, and I didn't know that a "doe" is a term for a female goat.

Comment: About Google Ngram, I suggest using *A few do, A few does* instead of *a few do, a few does*. By default, it's case sensitive.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Good to know!  That won't discriminate the case of  "'Did he take any?' 'A few.' 'Does she know?'"  Do you know if there's a way to insist on whitespace and no punctuation?

Comment: I'm sorry @Codeswitcher. I'm afraid I don't know that.